# SQL: Get latest location for each user

Tags: mysql, sql

I collect users location and then on a map I display each users latest location. I don't want to show ALL locations in the table, and only the latest. How would I do this?

```
select loc_userid, loc_lat, loc_lon, loc_date 
from friends f 
join location l
on l.loc_userid = f.friendid
where f.userid = 1
```

The code above searches the location table for all of the members locations who are friends with the userID specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT l.loc_userid, l.loc_lat, l.loc_lon, l.loc_date 
FROM friends f 
JOIN location l
ON l.loc_userid = f.friendid
WHERE f.userid = 1
ORDER BY f.loc_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one more `inner join` to filter out the latest location.

```
select l.loc_userid, l.loc_lat, l.loc_lon, l.loc_date 
from friends f 
inner join location l
on l.loc_userid = f.friendid
inner join (select loc_userid, MAX(loc_date) as max_loc_date 
            from location group by loc_userid) l2
on l.loc_userid = l2.loc_userid and l.loc_date = l2.loc_date
where f.userid = 1
```